# Target called via <phingcall> doesn't set properties in calling target

Tags: scope, phing

In the following phing xml, inside the "skel" target I check if the app is configured, if it's not then I call the configure target and then apply the config to several files.

The problem is that property `db.host` is not set after the phingcall, even though it is set after the propertyprompt.

What am I missing?

```
<!-- base configuration -->
<property name="paths.config" value="config" />
<property name="paths.config.file" value="${paths.config}/environment.ini" />

<available file="${paths.config.file}" property="configured" />

<target name="configure">
    <if>
     <equals arg1="${configured}" arg2="true" />
     <then>
       <echo message="Reconfigure ..." />
     </then>
     <else>
       <echo message="Configure ..." />
     </else>
    </if>

    <propertyprompt propertyName="db.host" defaultValue="localhost" promptText="Mysql Server Host" />
</target>

<target name="skel">
    <echo msg="Skel files..." />

    <if>
     <equals arg1="${configured}" arg2="${configured}" />
     <then>
       <echo message="Missing config file ..." />
       <phingcall target="configure" />
     </then>
    </if>

    <echo message="${db.host}" />
    <copy todir="config">
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.skel" to="*"/>
        <filterchain>
            <expandproperties />
        </filterchain>

        <fileset dir="config">
            <include name="*.skel" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the phingcall will create a new environment internally. When the configure target is done, this environment is out of scope.

This means it is not possible to use a separate configure target as you are suggesting.

The only solution might be to make the configure target create a configuration file which is used by the other targets.

Answer (score 2):

Properties set inside of targets are scoped to those targets and are not accessible outside their parent targets.

From [the documentation for `PropertyTask`](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#PropertyTask):

> **Important note about scope:** when the `<property>` tag is called inside a `<phingcall>` tag, any properties are set in a new local scope. Thus, any properties or other variables set inside that scope will cease to exist (or revert to their previous value) once the parent `<phingcall>` tag completes.